# HTML selection without copy permissions

Tags: javascript, html, selection

Is it possible to make selection of html without copy permissions?

I need to make text (complex HTML) be able selectalbe but:
1) I need to select only whole words (not characters
2) The selection should not copy text (with Ctrl+C)

Interesting example is in kindle cloud reader. But it seems that they practiced a rocket science to implement it.

Thanks

Comment: No. Besides, it's probably pointless to do so.

Comment: for the Ctrl+C you can prevent it by detecting the keypress and ignore it so as to prevent propagation.

Comment: Pointless? As I've said look at amazon kindle cloud reader. I'm not sure how they do it, but there really very sophisticated method applied.

Answer (score 2):

No matter what you do, text transmitted to a browser will in one way or another be copyable by the user. Even if you disabled right click copying and ctrl-c copying (which could easily be gotten around by disabling javascript), the user still has the option to view the page's source using their browser or plug in, and for the more clever, they can grab the text as it is transmitted to their browsers. Best bet would be turning the text into an image server side, but even then, OCR programs can turn this in to plain text.

Comment: Ok the task is actually not to create a DRM content. I found out that amazon uses overplayed styled divs to fake the text selection.